# Avoiding overlapping content when some dynamic elements need absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

There's a neat responsive org chart layout on codepen here: http://codepen.io/siiron/pen/aLkdE which uses absolute positioning to mimic the effect of the old-style organisation charts. However, it relies pretty heavily on absolute positioning elements in order to make the boxes appear in the right place.

This causes a problem when you try and drop this into your own document flow, overlapping with the content below it. Obviously, since it's designed to be responsive, you can't predict how high the content will be, and the way I'd like to implement it, the content for the boxes will be dynamic anyway - so adding a fixed-height div wrap wouldn't appear to be an option.

I've added a fiddle to demonstrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/yvjG4/

```
<style>
*{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}

/* Generic styling */

body{
    background: #F5EEC9;    
}

.content{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1142px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

a:focus{
    outline: 2px dashed #f7f7f7;
}

@media all and (max-width: 767px){
    .content{
        padding: 0 20px;
    }   
}

ul{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;       
}

ul a{
    display: block;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 4px solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: .7em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
    height: 70px;
    margin-bottom: -26px;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 9px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -webkit-transition: all linear .1s;
    -moz-transition: all linear .1s;
    transition: all linear .1s;
}


@media all and (max-width: 767px){
    ul a{
        font-size: 1em;
    }
}


ul a span{
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -0.7em;
    display: block;
}

/*

 */

.administration > li > a{
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.director > li > a{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto 0px auto;
}

.subdirector:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 130px;
    background: red;
    border-left: 4px solid #fff;
    left: 45.45%;
    position: relative;
}

.subdirector,
.departments{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.subdirector > li:first-child,
.departments > li:first-child{  
    width: 18.59894921190893%;
    height: 64px;
    margin: 0 auto 92px auto;       
    padding-top: 25px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid white;
    z-index: 1; 
}

.subdirector > li:first-child{
    float: right;
    right: 27.2%;
    border-left: 4px solid white;
}

.departments > li:first-child{  
    float: left;
    left: 27.2%;
    border-right: 4px solid white;  
}

.subdirector > li:first-child a,
.departments > li:first-child a{
    width: 100%;
}

.subdirector > li:first-child a{    
    left: 25px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 767px){
    .subdirector > li:first-child,
    .departments > li:first-child{
        width: 40%; 
    }

    .subdirector > li:first-child{
        right: 10%;
        margin-right: 2px;
    }

    .subdirector:after{
        left: 49.8%;
    }

    .departments > li:first-child{
        left: 10%;
        margin-left: 2px;
    }
}


.departments > li:first-child a{
    right: 25px;
}

.department:first-child,
.departments li:nth-child(2){
    margin-left: 0;
    clear: left;    
}

.departments:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 81.1%;
    height: 22px;   
    border-top: 4px solid #fff;
    border-right: 4px solid #fff;
    border-left: 4px solid #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 130px;
    left: 9.1%
}

@media all and (max-width: 767px){
    .departments:after{
        border-right: none;
        left: 0;
        width: 49.8%;
    }
}

.department:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 22px;
    border-left: 4px solid white;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -22px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -4px;
}

.department:first-child:before,
.department:last-child:before{
    border:none;
}

.department{
    border-left: 4px solid #fff;
    width: 18.59894921190893%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1.751313485113835%;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.lt-ie8 .department{
    width: 18.25%;
}

@media all and (max-width: 767px){
    .department{
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    .department:before{
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 0;
        height: 60px;
        border-left: 4px solid white;
        z-index: 1;
        top: -60px;
        left: 0%;
        margin-left: -4px;
    }

    .department:nth-child(2):before{
        display: none;
    }
}

.department > a{
    margin: 0 0 -26px -4px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.department > a:hover{  
    height: 80px;
}

.department > ul{
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.department li{ 
    padding-left: 25px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
    height: 80px;   
}

.department li a{
    background: #fff;
    top: 48px;  
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 90%;
    height: 60px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    right: -1px;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%) !important;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.25)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0)))!important;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%)!important;
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%)!important;
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%)!important;
    background-image: linear-gradient(135deg,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%)!important;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#40000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=1 );
}

.department li a:hover{
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 9px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    height: 80px;
    width: 95%;
    top: 39px;
    background-image: none!important;
}

/* Department/ section colors */
.department.dep-a a{ background: #FFD600; }
.department.dep-b a{ background: #AAD4E7; }
.department.dep-c a{ background: #FDB0FD; }
.department.dep-d a{ background: #A3A2A2; }
.department.dep-e a{ background: #f0f0f0; }
</style>

<h3>Some Content Above</h3>
<div class="content">
  <h1>Responsive Organization Chart</h1>
  <figure class="org-chart cf">
    <ul class="administration">
      <li>                  
        <ul class="director">
          <li>
            <a href="#"><span>Director</span></a>
            <ul class="subdirector">
              <li><a href="#"><span>Assistante Director</span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="departments cf">                             
              <li><a href="#"><span>Administration</span></a></li>

              <li class="department dep-a">
                <a href="#"><span>Department A</span></a>
                <ul class="sections">
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section A1</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section A2</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section A3</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section A4</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section A5</span></a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="department dep-b">
                <a href="#"><span>Department B</span></a>
                <ul class="sections">
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section B1</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section B2</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section B3</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section B4</span></a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="department dep-c">
                <a href="#"><span>Department C</span></a>
                <ul class="sections">
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section C1</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section C2</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section C3</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section C4</span></a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="department dep-d">
                <a href="#"><span>Department D</span></a>
                <ul class="sections">
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D1</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D2</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D3</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D4</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D5</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D6</span></a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="department dep-e">
                <a href="#"><span>Department E</span></a>
                <ul class="sections">
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section E1</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section E2</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section E3</span></a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>   
      </li>
    </ul>           
  </figure>
</div>
<h3>Some Content Below</h3>
```

Any ideas how the org chart layout could be wrangled into not overlapping content below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for,
 changes I made:

```
.departments{
    height:0;
    width: 100%;
}


@media all and (max-width: 767px){
    .department{
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yvjG4/30/

Answer (score 0):

One solution, perhaps not the most elegant, is to wrap each section into it's own div, and then give the div wrapping the org chart enough height to place the bottom content below the org chart.

html:

```
<div class="top-content"></div>
<div class="middle-content">
  // org chart here
</div>
<div class="footer-content"></div>
```

css:

```
.middle-content{
  position:relative;
  height:2500px;
}
```